# Executing a specific function based on a std::string

Tags: c++, templates, reflection, template-specialization

I am trying to write a program that will execute a function based on a string I fetch from a database.
Basically what I do is:

```
// Create an enum
enum AFunc{
 invalidFunction,
 function2,
 function3
}

// have a class handling the functions
struct A
{
  static AFunc resolveStringToFunction(std::string) {...}

  template<int T>
  void execute(...)
  {
     // this may not be called = invalidFunction
  }

  template<>
  void execute<1> (...)
  { 
     // do stuff = function1
  }

  template<>
  void execute<2> (...)
  { 
     // do stuff = function2
  }
};
```

In my application i do this:

```
A a;
std::string funcString = getFromDatabase (...) // Not really, but this is abstract
const AFunc funcType   = A::resolveStringToFunction(funcString);

a.execute<funcType>(...);
```

The problem here is that the compiler does not accept the dynamic calling of a template function, because (as I understood it) it needs to know which function is called by compile time.

**Is there any way around this?**

**Is there a better solution to this problem? Maybe a design pattern?**

Comment: `std::unordered_map<std::string, std::function<…>>`. I call it the "hash table from strings to functions" design pattern.

Comment: (also, if you don't know the names of the functions at compile-time, then you can always `dlopen()` and `dlsym()`. Or the equivalents thereof if you're running a stupid non-POSIX system like Windows. Might as well look up `extern "C"` linkage on the way.)

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant Yeah that's a solution i already tried but i thought "there has to be a better way" as i can't implement an interface with the functions - so the footprint of the static functions could vary and i would run into problems on runtime and not on compiletime, right?

Comment: if the types of your functions are heterogenous, then you will have to store the type as well and resort to plain old function pointers, casted to the appropriate type and invoked in different manners. There's no way around that – since C++ doesn't have run-time reflection.

Comment: okay, thanks! i'll post my solution as the answer when i'm done implementing it.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant: And it sounded like good advice until you started calling it a "design pattern"...

Comment: @KerrekSB exactly :P

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant I added the example code, it compiles, how is the style?

Comment: @FloWin It's fine. I'd use an `unordered_map` (since the order seems to have no significance) and an initializer list (in order not to have to `boost::assign`), though.

Answer (score 0):

```
namespace afunc // dont pollute global namespace
{

typedef std::function<void(...)> aFunc;
static function1(...)
{    
  // do stuff
}

static function2(...)
{    
  // do stuff
}

const std::unordered_map<std::string, aFunc> functions (
 {{"function1", &function1},{"function2", &function2}} ); // afunc
```

And it is called by the following code:

```
std::string funcString = getFromDatabase (...) // Not really, but this is abstract
afunc::functions.at(funcString)(...) // at because the map is const, so it's even threadsafe
```